# How to loop through my Json response using jQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, json

My Json response looks like:

```
[{"UserID": 1}, {"UserID", 324}]
```

I call the page to get json like:

```
$.get("myurl.aspx", {blah:1}, function(data) {

       $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
             alert(item.UserID);

       });

});
```

Firebug is reporting the error:

G is undefined.

Comment: you have a typo in second part of response, there should be a `:` instead of `,` in second object

Comment: there is a security risk in sending an array literal as a JSON response. Better to make it `{ items: [{"UserID": 1}, {"UserID": 324}] }`. Then your javascript will work too.

Comment: Gabe, how can I add that Items key?

Answer (score 6):

I think you want this instead since your data var doesn't have a property called items:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
     alert(item.UserID);
});
```

Comment: can I check for success of the ajax call? or its assumed?

Answer (score 2):

It appears your response is not a true JSON object.  Notice that there is a comma instead of a colon in your response.

If that's just a typo, check the request and response in the Firebug console (on the Net tab) to see what data is being sent to the `myurl.aspx` page.  You should see your AJAX request, as well as the data that is being sent back to your page.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to pass a data type parameter to [`get`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get) so that it knows to expect JSON, or use [`getJSON`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you posted is invalid:

```
[{"UserID": 1}, {"UserID", 324}]
```

Notice the comma on the second UserID.

Answer (score 1):

By default, ASP.Net encapsulates the JSON object in another object named 'd'.  Your response would look like this then:

```
{"d": [{"UserID": 1}, {"UserID": 324}]}
```

Try this:

```
$.get("myurl.aspx", {blah:1}, function(data) {

   $.each(data.d, function(i, item) {
         alert(item.UserID);
   });
});
```

Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd448975%28VS.100%29.aspx) for Microsoft's reasoning (bottom of the page.)