# Loop through json response with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

```
 {
    "Items": [{
        "id": "96",
        "user_id": "1090",
        "points": "120",
        "payment_id": null,
        "reason_id": "1",
        "reference": "",
        "point_date": ""
    }]
}
```

My `success` function looks like this :

```
success: function(jsonResponse) {
}
```

Please help me on looping this with jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For best results, please tell us what you expect to happen, show what you have tried, and explain how that attempt failed to meet your goal.

Comment: i can give you many links [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251772/loop-json-response-after-ajax-success) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208270/how-to-loop-through-my-json-response-using-jquery)

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse)); i have alerted all the array values but i need to retrieve only id values

Comment: `jsonResponse[0].id` will give you the first id value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use `$.each` or such, assuming `Items` `[]` has multiple objects. There are many iterative functions in jQuery like `map` and `each`. Choose one which best fits your needs. To select `Items` `[]` from `jsonResponse`, use

var items = jsonResponse.Items;

This is how an `each` function will look like :

```
//empty array for your ids
var ids = [];
//each function for iteration
$.each(items, function(i, item) {
  ids.push(item.id);
});
//done. now check if its all there 
alert(JSON.stringify(ids));
```

Or you could also use `for` loop :

```
//empty array for your ids
var ids = [], i=0;
//for loop for iteration
for( ; i < items.length, i++)
{
  ids.push(items[i].id);
};
//done. now check if its all there 
alert(JSON.stringify(ids));
```

Or, simply use `map` :

```
var ids = $.map(items, function(item, i) {
     //return id from item object
     return item.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the $.each() function in order to traverse the JSON:

```
var jsonData = {"Items": [{"id":"96","user_id":"1090","points":"120","payment_id":null,"reason_id":"1","reference":"","point_date":""}]}

$(jsonData.Items).each(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

This would alert each id in the Items list. In this use case there is only one object.

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/mN449/